# Usage of properties not backed by instance variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, instance-variables, accessor

Class.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIFont *font;
```

Class.m:

```
@interface Class()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *titleLabel;

@end

- (void)setFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    self.titleLabel.font = font;
}

- (UIFont *)font
{
    return self.titleLabel.font;
}
```

In this example, the `font` property declared in `Class.h` does not have a backing instance variable as both accessors are overridden, but is rather being used as a "proxy" onto `titleLabel.font`, which cannot otherwise be accessed from outside the class because it isn't in the public interface.

Is this a legitimate usage of overriding accessors, or are there pitfalls to this approach? Do property attributes e.g. `strong`, `weak` make any difference here?

Comment: Another way of thinking about this is that the property *does* have a backing instance variable; it is `self.titleLabel.font`.  There is no conceptual difference between what you have done and creating your own set/get methods that access `_font`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing here is perfectly fine. Properties don't have to be backed by an ivar.

I've written properties where the setter and getter simply write/read the value to/from `NSUserDefaults`.

As for whether such a property should be `strong` or `weak`, etc., you should base that on the "contract" you wish to provide to the client of the property. In the case you posted, you should make your property the same as the property you are proxying (which you are doing for `font`).